# Tiberius Gracchus' strategy after Punic Wars

Tags: ancient-rome

Did Tiberius Gracchus' strategy as tribune worked towards the best interests of the Republic, given the political, social, and economic climate after the Punic Wars?

Comment: This could have simply been reworded instead of put on hold.